# Does $f(z)= \frac{z^5}{|z|^4} , \forall z \neq 0, ; f(0)=0$ satisfy Cauchy Riemann Equations?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

In my book it is given that $$f(z)=\frac{z^5}{|z|^4} ,\forall z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}; f(0)=0$$
Satisfy Cauchy Riemann Equations at $z=0$ but not differentiable at $z=0$.

But while checking it does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann Equations itself...

Because $$f_x(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{h^5}{h^4}}{h}$$ $$=1$$

Therefore $f_x(0)=1$

Similarly proceeding for $f_y(0)$
We get

$$f_y(0)=\lim_{ih \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(ih)-f(0)}{ih}$$ $$ = \frac{\frac{(ih)^5}{h^4}}{ih}$$ $$ = 1$$

therefore we got $$f_x(0)=f_y(0)=1$$

But by the Cauchy Reimann equations $f_x(z)=-i f_y(z)$ and hence the CR equations isn't satisfied...

Am I doing this correctly? Is there any other way to do this?

```
EDIT:- My mistake...It satisfies CR equations at z=0.
```

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{z^3}{\bar z^2}$, and in particular $\partial_{\bar z} f(z) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you verify CR equations, treat $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ as an $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping. There is no $i$ in the increment $h$ in $y$. It should be

$$
f_y(z)=f_y(x+iy)=\lim_{\mathbb{R}\ni h\to0}(f(x+i(y+h))-f(x+iy))/h.
$$

For $z=0$:
$$
f_y(0)=\lim_{\mathbb{R}\ni h\to 0}(f(ih)-f(0))/h=(ih^5/h^4)/h=i.
$$

---

**Edit:** I see the confusion is the difference between the complex derivative and real partial derivatives. For notations, let us define:

$$
f_x:=u_x+iv_x,\quad f_y:=u_v+iv_y.
$$

This may differ from  BrianMoehring's comment, but it's just a matter of notation. I am using this notation because OP wrote the CR equations as $f_x=-if_y$.

Now let's make clear the difference between the complex derivative and real partial derivatives:

- **Real partial derivatives**: Derivative computed by incrementing $x$ or $y$ with real increment $h\in\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, under this definition, $f_x$ and $f_y$ denote real partial derivatives of $f$ (considered as $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$).
- **Complex derivatives**: Derivative computed by incrementing $z$ by a complex increment $h\in\mathbb{C}$, denoted by $f'(z)$.
- **Complex directional derivatives**: Derivative computed by incrementing $z$ by a complex increment $h\in\mathbb{C}$, but along a specific complex direction: $h=re$ where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $e\in\mathbb{C}$ with norm 1. Let us denote this by $f'_e(z)$.

CR equations can be derived from this obvious observation:

> If $f'(z)$ exists, then $f'_e(z)$ should exist for all directions $e$, and in particular, $e=1$ and $e=i$.

The observation suggests:
$$
f'_{e=1}(z)=f'_{e=i}(z).
$$
We can compute these two complex directional derivatives as
$$
\begin{align}
f'_{e=1}(z)&=\lim_{\mathbb R\ni r\to0}(f(z+r)-f(z))/r\\
&=\lim_{\mathbb R\ni r\to0}(f(x+r+iy)-f(x+iy))/r\\
&=u_x+iv_x=f_x
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
f'_{e=i}(z)&=\lim_{\mathbb R\ni r\to0}(f(z+ir)-f(z))/(ir)\\
&=\lim_{\mathbb R\ni r\to0}(f(x+i(y+r))-f(x+iy))/(ir)\\
&=-i(u_y+iv_y)=-if_y
\end{align}
$$

The mistake in the original question is that $f_y$ is first computed as the complex directional derivative, but then also used in CR equations as a real partial derivative. These two are different as explained above.

Comment: No, We cannot consider like this... because the increment here is $ih$ and not $h$, It

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP What do you mean? $f_x(0)=1=-if_y(0)=(-i)i=1$ is satisfied.

Comment: we know that $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can be considered as $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ and if by your argument the increment is only h then every function which is differentiable in $R^2$ can be seen in complex plane and hence will be holomorphic... EVEN IF IT DOESN'T SATISFY CR EQUATIONS... BUT THAT'S NOT TRUE.   I meant that if the increment is simply h, then there is no difference between differentiability in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP My argument is "When you check CR equations, compute $f_x$ and $f_y$ as if $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$", **NOT** "any differentiable $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ function is holomorphic if you think of them as $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$". To make an $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ function holomorphic as $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, it needs to satisfy CR equations.

Comment: ok Let's consider your argument and derive CR equations... what will we get? we get $f_x(z)=u_x+iv_x$ and $f_y(z)=u_y+iv_y$ and if the derivative exists both should be equal and so $u_x=u_y$ and $v_x=v_y$ which is definitely not CR equations

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP You are confusing partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ (as $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping) with the complex derivative $f'(z)$ (as $\mathbb{C}$ mapping). $f_x=f_y$ is wrong. Let $f_x=u_x+iv_x$ and $f_y=u_y+iv_y$ as above. **If $f'(z)$ exists**, then it must equal $f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\mathbb{R}}(f(z+h)-f(z))/h=u_x+iv_x=f_x$ and also $f'(z)=\lim_{ih\to0,\ h\in\mathbb{R}}(f(z+ih)-f(z))/(ih)=(-i)(u_y+iv_y)=(-i)f_y$. This is how to correctly derive the CR equation.

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP Note $f_y(z) \neq u_y + iv_y$.  Rather, $if_y(z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(z)) = u_y+iv_y$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I said if the increment is only $h$ instead of $ih$ we will get $f_y(z)=u_y+iv_y$... pardon me if I am wrong

Comment: Do you agree the imaginary part of a complex number is a real number?  If so, it makes no sense to increment the imaginary part by $ih$.  It's a real number.  You increment it by a real $h$ (this is equivalent to incrementing $z$ by $ih$, and if you are careful with your functions both give the same result)

Comment: My point with the first comment is that correctly incrementing $y$ by a real $h$, as is proposed by trisct, does not give $f_y(z) = u_y + iv_y$.  Correctly doing it gives $if_y(z) = u_y + iv_y$ because the left-hand side of $f = u+iv$ is a function of the form $f(x+iy)$, not $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP I made an edit to clarify things

Comment: @trisct  I understood. while proving CR equations for $f_y$ we take the increment as $ih$ and then factor out the $\frac{1}{i}$ and so we get the partial derivative with respect to imaginary part of the function and proceed. But What I did in this question was I mimicked the proof, but forgot to factor out $1/i$ in this case it will be enough to check $f_x=f_y$ but there I tried to use CR equation verification.(A Dumb move by me) Sorry for wasting your time guys. Thank you so much for making this much of effort to make me understand my mistake.. finally Is my argument in this comment correct?